# Parallelism and Shared memory in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I've read through the parallel computing documentation and experimented with some examples of my own, but I still have some questions about the fundamentals of parallel programming in Julia:

1. If I want to use the @parallel macro on a PC with 4 cores, is there a "cap" on the number of processors I can add to my environment? I know we can add more workers than the number of cores and it is up to the scheduler to assign a process to some core, but what is the logical limit for the number of processes to be assigned to a core?
2. Following the setting described in (1), if I have an array that will hold some computed values, and I parallelize the computations over each row over a different worker process, will this be an example of a **SharedArray** or **DistributedArray**? My code looks something like this:

```
using Distributed
@everywhere function parareal(a, b, nC, nF, K, y0, f, coarseSolver, fineSolver)
      fine_solve = zeros(nC,nF+1,K);
      @sync for i=1:nC
           fine_solve[i,1,k] = correctC[i,k-1];
           for j = 2:(nF + 1)
              @spawn fine_solve[i, j, k] = fiPEvaled(xF[i, j - 1], fine_solve[i, j - 1, k])
           end
      end
end
```

From what I understand a SharedArray is allows the same memory area to be accessible by all processes, which is how I have defined my array?

I am relatively new to parallel computing in Julia, so I apologize for the vague descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, Julia uses a scheduler to assign workers to available processing cores. There is no logical limit for workers per core, but OTOH if there are many threads waiting for core time, execution may be slower than looping among fewer threads. The scheduler has had changes between Julia versions, so that which core gets which thread in a situation where threads outnumber cores has changed between Julia version 1.0 and current Julia. For current details, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/.

To answer your second question, a shared (or a distributed) array is one which is accessed by more than one process. This would include arrays defined before the threads are created. @everywhere allows the code defined as @everywhere to be executed only once in a context shared by all processes, so an array defined with @everywhere is effectively treated similarly as if defined for all threads prior to thread creation (though races can occur with @everywhere initialization that would not occur in code run entirely before thread creation).

As an example of all of these:

```
using Distributed

@assert Threads.nthreads() > 4 # we want enough threads for simultaneity

const globalarr = falses(4)

@sync for i in 1:4
    @async begin
        @everywhere earr1 = falses(4)
        localarr = falses(4)
        globalarr[i], localarr[i] = true, true
        sleep(rand())
        @everywhere earr2 = falses(4)
        earr1[i], earr2[i] = true, true
        @show i, globalarr, earr1, earr2, localarr
    end
end

output:

(i, globalarr, earr1, earr2, localarr) = (3, Bool[1, 1, 1, 1], Bool[0, 0, 1, 0], Bool[0, 0, 1, 0], Bool[0, 0, 1, 0])
(i, globalarr, earr1, earr2, localarr) = (2, Bool[1, 1, 1, 1], Bool[0, 1, 1, 0], Bool[0, 1, 1, 0], Bool[0, 1, 0, 0])
(i, globalarr, earr1, earr2, localarr) = (4, Bool[1, 1, 1, 1], Bool[0, 1, 1, 1], Bool[0, 0, 0, 1], Bool[0, 0, 0, 1])
(i, globalarr, earr1, earr2, localarr) = (1, Bool[1, 1, 1, 1], Bool[1, 1, 1, 1], Bool[1, 0, 0, 0], Bool[1, 0, 0, 0])
```

The `globalarr` behaves as expected.  Each thread changes its `i`th bit to true. The `localarr` shows that each thread modifies its own copy of `localarr`. The `earr1` and `earr2` bitsets, defined as `@everywhere`, suffer from race condition errors which depend on which thread gets to that `@everywhere` line first (a race condition). `@everywhere` is therefore best used with code that is synchronized to avoid race and other timing errors in a way the above `for` loop is not.

In your code, @everywhere for the function itself may not be needed, and since both the function and its variable `fine_solve` is defined before threads are created, your code will work fine as long as each thread only modifies its own part of `fine_solve`. This is true in your code since each thread accesses a different portion of `fine_solve`, as defined by a unique value of `j`.

Answer (score 0):

`Distributed` isn't shared memory parallelism. For shared memory, you should typically use `@threads`/`@spawn` which uses multi-threadng rather than multi-process.